# What mistake am I committing while trying to match the email address using RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to check the format of *email address* using the following script but somewhere I am making a mistake.As I try to match the pattern `reg_1` with `str_1 , str_2, str_3` I get false. Why is that ?

```
var reg_1 = /^[a-zA-Z][0-9_.][@]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9][.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]$/;
var id_1 = "suhailgupta03@gmail.com";
var id_2 = "gupta.suhail@rediff.com";
var id_3 = "suhail_gupta03@ovi.com";

document.write(reg_1.test(id_1));
document.write("<br / >" + reg_1.test(id_2));
document.write("<br / >" + reg_1.test(id_3));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the character class notation `[...]`. For example, `[a-zA-Z][0-9_.]` means "a letter `a-z` or `A-Z`, followed by a digit `0-9` or underscore `_` or dot `.`".

I guess what you want is:

```
var reg_1 = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
```

In addition to the really necessary changes, I also performed a bit of cleanup: specifically, I changed `[@]` to just `@` (there was no reason to wrap it in a character class) and `[.]` to `\.` (likewise, except that `.` needs to be escaped when you mean "dot" rather than "any character"), and I removed the `{1}` (since that's implicit anyway).

(But note that this isn't a general-purpose e-mail-address-validation regex. E-mail addresses are actually insanely complicated, and the only way to really validate one is to send an e-mail to it and see if it arrives!)

Comment: I am sorry but how is `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` different from mine ? I haven't understood it.

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Do you understand what `[a-zA-Z0-9_.]` means?

Comment: yeah I guess. Any character between `a-z` or `A-Z` or `0-9` or `_` or `.`

Comment: @SuhailGupta: O.K., and do you understand what `[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+` means?

Comment: yeah.`+` is a repetition quantifier.This pattern matches any string containing `[a-zA-Z0-9_.]` I guess

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+` means "one or more letters/digits/underscores/dots". Do you see how that's different from `[a-zA-Z][0-9_.]`, which means "exactly one letter, followed by exactly one digit/underscore/dot"?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.  I was actually just writing a blog post as to why this is a flawed approach: [How to (not) Validate an Email Address](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2013/02/how-to-not-validate-email-address.html)

In summary, something like this should be more than sufficient:

```
var emailValidation = /.+@.+\..+/;
console.log(emailValidation.exec("user@example.com") != null); // Result: "true"
console.log(emailValidation.exec("www.example.com") != null); // Result: "false"
```

Comment: Your regex can be further shorten to just `/.@.+\../` - since you don't use any anchor anyway...

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you are looking for a string that begins with two characters followed by an @ sign, and none of your emails starts like that.